# Is it possible to use unary function instead of binary in `flip`?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, flip

The type of the `Prelude` function `flip` is:

```
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

I.e., it takes one binary function and two arguments.

The type of the `Prelude` function `id` is:

```
id :: a -> a
```

But the type of `flip id` is:

```
flip id :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
```

How is it possible to apply `flip` to `id` when `id` is a unary function and `flip` requires binary function for the first arg?

btw. `flip id` is similar to `\ x f -> f x`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Haskell makes `id` fit the type of the first argument to `flip` by setting `a = b -> c`.  So:

```
flip :: ( a       -> b -> c) -> b ->  a       -> c
flip :: ((b -> c) -> b -> c) -> b -> (b -> c) -> c
flip id ::                      b -> (b -> c) -> c
```

where `id` is taken to be of type

```
id :: (b -> c) ->  b -> c
```

which is equivalent to

```
id :: (b -> c) -> (b -> c)
```

i.e. a specialisation of `id` that only applies to unary functions.

Edit: I think I might rephrase my first line as:
Haskell *deduces* that `id` fits the type of the first argument to `flip` *if* `a = b -> c`.
In case that's any clearer.

Comment: I forgot that the general type identifier `a` can be a function too, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Nefrubyr explains it very well.
Another way to (hopefully) make this a bit more intuitive is to think of the function application operator `($)`.

`($)` is a specialized form of `id`:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b)
($) = id
```

I've seen the definition `(#) = flip ($)`, such that you can write the argument before the function its applied to: `obj # show`.

Obviously, since `($)` is just a specialized form of `id`, you could also write: `(#) = flip id`